# MySQL Left Join not returning null values for joined table

Tags: mysql, join, null

Please help me with the following MySQL query, which joins two tables (A and B):

```
SELECT * from A
left join B on A.sid = B.sid
where (rCode = 1 Or rCode = 2 Or rCode = 3 Or rCode = 5)
AND (rYear = 2011 or rYear is null)
```

`roleCode` is a field in table A and `rYear` is a field in table B

The result set is not as expected. Only 185 rows are returned, but there are 629 rows in table A that match the where condition. Shouldn't the rows without a matching row in table B be returned with null values for their B fields?

Comment: 1859 rows with rCode in (1,2,3,5)?

Comment: Yes, the problem isn't in your join, get rid of it and see what the results are.

Comment: Sorry - there are 629 rows in table A that match the where condition.

Comment: Your logic is flawed that the results are incorrect with what you stated. The `AND` part of the statement could effectively return 0 results. If the row joins and it has a value other than 2011 it will not match. So your query could be completely correct and not return all the results that match just the first `WHERE` condition

Comment: @nate wrong interpretation. see my answer

Comment: @Richard: interpretative dance is down the hall and to the left. SQL is logic based. There is no evidence that the query is incorrect. You should see the *upvoted* answer (that was shown to work) as it basically is saying the same thing as I.

Comment: @nate Do you even understand that Jage's query is ***functionally equivalent*** to the OP's own? In other words, the scale of change, **functionally** is the same as wilbbe01's answer - a non-event

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should not specify rYear in a WHERE clause. Those limit your results after the join. You should specify rYear in an ON clause to get back records with NULL from table B.

```
SELECT * from A
left join B 
on A.sid = B.sid 
AND (rYear = 2011 or rYear is null)
where (rCode = 1 Or rCode = 2 Or rCode = 3 Or rCode = 5)
```

Comment: Hi Jage. This works great! However, have I misunderstood the MySQL documentation? SQL Server would return a load of nulls for the original query. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html - specifically: "If there is a row in A that matches the WHERE clause, but there is no row in B that matches the ON condition, an extra B row is generated with all columns set to NULL."

Comment: you don't need the *rYear IS NULL* in the JOIN condition. using `ON a.sid = b.sid AND rYear = 2011` is enough

Comment: @a_h // doesn't explain why the WHERE .. (OR rYear IS NULL) doesn't work? Any thoughts? In fact, if rYear is nullable, Jage's query and your suggestion return different data

Comment: @Richard: yes you are right. I was a bit too quick. Of course it makes a difference. Sorry (to Jage as well)

Answer (score 1):

Greg, is that really all there is to the query?

Sample tables

```
create table A(rCode int, sid int);
insert A select 1,1;
insert A select 2,3;
insert A select 3,2;
insert A select 5,4;
insert A select 1,5;
create table B(rYear int, sid int);
insert B select 2011,1;
insert B select null,3;
insert B select 2011,2;
insert B select 2015,2;
```

Queries:

```
SELECT * from A
left join B on A.sid = B.sid
where (rCode = 1 Or rCode = 2 Or rCode = 3 Or rCode = 5)
AND (rYear = 2011 or rYear is null);

SELECT * from A
left join B on A.sid = B.sid AND (rYear = 2011 or rYear is null)
where (rCode = 1 Or rCode = 2 Or rCode = 3 Or rCode = 5);
```

Both of the queries are exactly the same, both returning:

```
rCode       sid         rYear       sid
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           2011        1
2           3           NULL        3
3           2           2011        2
5           4           NULL        NULL
1           5           NULL        NULL
```

So I am surprised that Jage's query (the 2nd option) works for you but not your original.  It would be different story without the inner `or rYear is null`.

Think of the LEFT JOIN like this [1]

```
SELECT * from A
left join B on A.sid = B.sid
```

Keep everything in A, and where matched in the ON clause, keep B otherwise pad B columns with NULL.  Add the WHERE clause [2]

```
where (rCode = 1 Or rCode = 2 Or rCode = 3 Or rCode = 5)
AND (rYear = 2011 or rYear is null);
```

Using the output from [1], CUT down based on the filter, applied AFTER the left join.  With the `rYear is null`, it should still keep all A records, on the proviso that the rCode filter is matched.  However, if the filter in rYear is only

```
AND (rYear in (2011,2012))
```

It's a different story, because where B was not matched, the rYear was padded with NULL, which won't match the rYear filter -> the entire row gets removed, including the A record.  Such a filter on rYear would have gone into the ON clause as shown below, otherwise might as well make it an INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT * from A
left join B on A.sid = B.sid AND (rYear in (2011,2012))
where (rCode = 1 Or rCode = 2 Or rCode = 3 Or rCode = 5)
```

Comment: Really helpful Richard thank you. There are several other fields in the tables and the query was a lot larger, but I cut the query down when trying to solve the problem, but also so it would be easier to read on here. Jage's solution was the only one I could get to work. If you give me your email I can send you details of the tables complete if you're interested? I've only ever done left joins in SQL Server it's a first for me in MySQL! :)

Comment: @Greg If you've done them in SQL Server, then you've done them in MySQL. They are the same. See the last bits about ON and WHERE clause differences, they should get you through.